# VSCODE - How to auto closing html code of ruby on rails html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby, visual-studio-code

I want to auto closing the html code in the html.erb file. 
What should I do?

#### `Added screenshots`

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Install the Ruby extension.
2. Add this to your user settings:

   ```
   "emmet.includeLanguages": {"erb": "html"}
   ```

Example with erb and ruby:

[image: VSCode User Settings]

Comment: That way, auto closing works for html code in .html.erb, but it does not work for ruby ​​code.

Is there any way I can use both?

Comment: Sure, you can add this to your user settings: `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"erb": "html", "ruby": "html"}`

Comment: im sorry
I set the following in `emmet.includeLanguages` ::
`"files.associations": {
        "erb": "html", "ruby": "html"
    }`
But still html code in .html.erb does not auto close

Comment: It looks like a screenshot but still does not auto close
Results modified the post

Comment: @bryanlo22 Why not ```"emmet.includeLanguages": {"html.erb": "html"```? What's the difference between that and ```"emmet.includeLanguages": {"erb": "html"}```?

Answer (score 25):

You don't need to install any extension, just add this to you User `settings.json` file in VSCode at the end of the file, and it will work like a charm.

```
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"html.erb": "html", "erb": "html"}
```

[More info about emmet suggestion ordering](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-suggestion-ordering)

Comment: Settings file can be found at this path File>Preferences>Settings>Extensions>Emmet>Edit in settings.json

Answer (score 8):

Install [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) Extension

html.erb file is included by default

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.